# How many free mapviews can I do with my Android app + Google Maps Android API?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

With Google Maps API, you have a limited # of free mapviews (25000 per day) before you start to pay (0,5$ per day/1000 mapviews) or buy a premium license (1M mapviews per year).

But my quesiton is:

I want to attach a google map inside of my Android App, but I'm wondering about how many free mapviews can I do? Does it work like Google Maps API? Do not we have a limited number of mapviews?

The reason why I'm asking this is because I want to geolocalize my inicial coordinates and then, "draw" the path that I follow in a Google Map (depending of the # of mapviews..refreshing it more or less usual).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlimited. Native maps API for Android is not affected by restrictions.
See https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's true, we just need to pay for:

Google Maps JavaScript API v2
Google Maps JavaScript API v3
Google Maps API for Flash
Google Maps Image APIs:
Google Static Maps API
Google Street View Image API