# Google MAPs API for android limit 2500 requests/day is per client device or per application key?

Tags: android, google-maps, limit, google-maps-android-api-2, license-key

Sorry, I found similar questions - but not the answers: only discussions. I'm developing android application which is intended to place points and draw routes on map. In case Google limits using of their maps 2500 r/day per key - there is no way to use it, since even in case your application was once sold - you'll need to pay every month for every additional 1000 req/day. Especially it is unclear for free application: how much it will cost for 100000 downloads per month after 1 year? Please, share your experience (not your assumptions). Thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I have same issue. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, Nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use of the Google Places API for Android request based on Application key based. 
After 150000 request per day whoever using your application "that means the "key" 
which you given for google places api request" will get a response error
from google api as "USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED" like
```

[USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED](https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage#status-codes)

```
while giving search text in search view(to check the response debug and see
the Exception occurs while sending request to place api) , but it wont't be 
visible to the user who uses you app. It will simply shows no 
movement in markers and no auto suggestion will come. For that you want to use
```

[Uplift](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/uplift#ensure_that_your_application_complies_with_the_api_terms_of_service)

```
for unlimited request. but it contains lots of restrictions by google. They
will track your app closely. If any violations of google policy happens means 
you app will get banned from GooglePlay Markert. so make sure in that you
app does't contains any violation policy before using this.
```

Comment: That's Google Places API, not Google Maps API.

Answer (score 14):

It is not entirely clear which limit you are looking for because the "usage of maps" can follow into a number of different map API categories.  For just displaying maps, you can display unlimited maps without usage limits on moblie apps using the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) -- the supporting documentation comes from the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis).

> The Maps API usage limits apply only to the following Maps API
>   services:
>
> ```
> Google Maps JavaScript API v2
> Google Maps JavaScript API v3
> Google Maps API for Flash
> Google Maps Image APIs:
>     Google Static Maps API
>     Google Street View Image API
> ```

Note that Google Maps Android API v2 does *not* appear on the list, and thus, is not subject to usage limits.

However, your question seems to be asking about routing, not maps.  If you need routes, you need to use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), which is not part of Google Maps Android API v2, and subject to its own [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits).  Specifically, 2500 requests *per key* per day.  Since directions is not tied to mobile app, it has no notion of a device.

In summary, if you want to display a map with a route you have generated on your own, there are no limits.  If you need Google to give you the route, you can only do 2500 requests for routes per day.  If you need more, you have to get a Google Maps API for Business account or find another routing solution.

Comment: I'm unclear how the Google Directions API requiests may be limited per key while the key is not a part of request: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters. Sonds more logically that restriction is per IP, i.e. device. Could you please clarify this point?

Comment: From [directions API website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key): All Directions API applications should use an API key. Including a key in your request: 1)  Allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the APIs Console. 2) Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits. 3) Ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. 
The Directions API uses an API key to identify your application. API keys are managed through the Google APIs console

Answer (score 2):

From FAQ google maps API: 
*"The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits."*

Answer (score 0):

Google has shared the API licensing structure. See link below.
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing

Comment: He's not talking about those API's. He's referring to the Google Maps for Android API v2.

Comment: I am well aware of the distinction. Strange enough the google licensing for business does not seem to make that distinction.

Comment: @moxin - I found different answers: for example here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973502/how-many-free-mapviews-can-i-do-with-my-android-app-google-maps-android-api?rq=1) the answer is that there is no limit at all for Android... The problem that there is no one answer from someone who had an experience OR official answer from Google. Another one vital question: if the limit exists, it is per device (which is more than enough) OR per key (and this mean this library is totally useless).

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers as the links may die.